# Expo: Failed to set an indexed property on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': Indexed property setter is not supported

Tags: react-native, expo, storybook, react-native-elements

when I click on **ADDONS** button on story page, I get the following error:

```
Failed to set an indexed property on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': Indexed property setter is not supported
```

This is my story:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "@rneui/themed";

const MyButtonMeta = {
  title: "MyButton",
  component: Button,
  argTypes: {
    onPress: { action: "pressed the button" },
  },
  args: {
    title: "Hello world",
    color: "error",
  },
  decorators: [(Story) => <Story />],
};

export default MyButtonMeta;

export const Basic = {};

export const AnotherExample = {
  args: {
    title: "Another example",
    color: "error",
  },
};
```

**there are some issues with color property because if I remove this, everything works fine!**

Any idea? tnx

- expo SDK **49**
- react-native-elements (rneui) **4.0.0-rc.8**
- @storybook/react-native **6.5.6**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I placed the color inside an array.

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "@rneui/themed";

const MyButtonMeta = {
  title: "MyButton",
  component: Button,
  argTypes: {
    onPress: { action: "pressed the button" },
  },
  args: {
    title: "Hello world",
  },
  decorators: [
    (Story) => <Story />
  ],
};

export default MyButtonMeta;

export const Basic = {
  args: {
    title: "Basic",
    type: 'clear',
    color: ['warning']  // <------- HERE
  },
};

export const AnotherExample = {
  args: {
    title: "Another example",
  },
};
```